# Save and iterate over a file continuously with python. What could be a good option?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

For arguments sake :) I have a CSV in witch I have to check if there are some elements in there, if I can't find them in the CSV append them in a new row, otherwise pass.

The idea is that it is a "forever" loop for a webscraping, I have to continuously check the events. Let's say it has to continouusly analize a list of future races on a betting webpage and when certain conditions are met has to place a bet, like if the total sum of money that is been bet on race is grater then 5000. I didn't include that code in here because that works well. Now I'm stock at the stage where I have to save the race that meets the condition, so it won't bet at each loop on the race that it has already made the bet.

So first it has to analize the races, has to decide if there  is the condition met, in the future will be more then one condition, and if the condition is met save the data, in some form, so it can be analized in the future and take decisions regarding the strategy.

I think that the problem relay on the fact that I haven't build the logic correctly.

And now I'll describe my problem:

Let's say that on each loop I'm been provided with an entire row, through different variables like:

Loop 1.

```
data = '26 Aug'
hour = '07:34'
race = "['Moci']"
country = '(RO)'
money = '7807'
against_odds = '2.1'
jokey = 'Dude\nGeorge'
```

At these point the condition of variable "money" it's been met so it has to check if this event is already in the csv or not. Let's say it's the first race scraped so it's not in the list, it has to put it in.  And the loop starts again in this case.

Loop 2.

```
data = '26 Aug'
hour = '07:41'
race = "['Cairo']"
country = '(EG)'
money = '14021'
against_odds = '3.1'
jokey = 'Boy\nOrange'
```

At these point in the loop will evaluate again the first race (aka loop 1) finds it in the csv and pass it. Then evaluates the values in the loop 2, and if the condition is met write it to csv and so on.

After the first loop, it should evaluate if the variables "hour" and "race" (it is important that it analyze only this two, because with the exception of "country" and "data" the other ones can be different at each iteration).

And now I simulate a forever loop:

```
x = 0
while x < 10:

with open('output_races.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
```

Then I do the "illogical part" where I have to check if the "hour" and "race" are in the CSV:

```
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] == hour and row[2] == race:
            pass
            print('in list')
        else:
             with open('output_races.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csv_file:
                 writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                 writer.writerow([date_01, hour, race, country, money, against_odds, jokey])
                 csv_file.close()
        print("wasn't in list")
        break
    x += 1
```

The idea is that, once working, it should search in the CSV for the last 5 to 8 positions, lets say, the events that once written it should skipped them at the next iteration. But my "illogical test" doesn't check them properly and I can't figure it out what may be the fallacy in my reasoning.

This is my CSV after each iteration, it can't do the comparison properly and at each loop just append it anyway, "at it's own will" :)

```
Date,Hour,Race,Country,Money,Against_odds,Jokey
26 Aug,07:34,['Moci'],(RO),7807,2.1,"Dude
George"
26 Aug,07:34,['Moci'],(RO),7807,2.1,"Dude
George"
26 Aug,07:34,['Moci'],(RO),7807,2.1,"Dude
George"
26 Aug,07:34,['Moci'],(RO),7807,2.1,"Dude
George"
26 Aug,07:41,['Cairo'],(EG),14021,3.1,"Boy
Orange"
26 Aug,07:41,['Cairo'],(EG),14021,3.1,"Boy
Orange"
26 Aug,07:41,['Cairo'],(EG),14021,3.1,"Boy
Orange"
```

I've made the changes "manually" to write the "Cairo" race. I think you'll get the point, you guys are more experienced.

I've tried this with a DataFrame but there I've found in the doc that it isn't recommended to iterate over a CSV that you modify constantly by the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), because "the iterator returns the copy not the view, and writing will have no effect". And the "illogical part" was quite similar.

So my question as a newbie if it is a possible to solve this mystery or should I search for another way to to save and analyze a continuous stream of data, what other ways to do this are out there?

Thanks!

Comment: `if row[1] == hour and row[2] == race:` what is hour and race? Also, row[1] and row[2] is not row 1 and 2, they are 2nd and third element of row

Comment: where is this data coming from? are you actually pulling the data from a url? otherwise, why would you want to repeatedly read in the data? But more importantly, please narrow the scope of your question. It's really difficult to tell what exactly you're having a hard time with. See the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - thanks! :)

Comment: @Epsi95 hour and race are: hour = '07:41' and race = "['Cairo']". I know that they are 2nd and 3rd elements of the row, that why I have to check them if there are in the CSV or not.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I didn't thought that it is important where the data is coming from, since that thing it it working like "a charm". I have already build the scraper that pulls the data from a live betting website that allows for the data to be scraped.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to do this continuously. Just read the CSV into memory once, then examine the in-memory representation. Basically, use a dict with the concatenation of the two variables as the key, or a set containing them if you don't care what the previously seen rows looked like.

Comment: @tripleee the thing is that I'll like to save the data as well for future analysis

Comment: Then by all means save it to your CSV file, but I still can't see a case for _reading_ the file repeatedly, unless you are running several scrapers in parallel and having all of them write to the same file (which then will have additional problems; maybe use a database instead of a flat text file if you need this to work).

Comment: `writer.writerow([date_01, hour, race, country, money, against_odds, jokey])` are you writing old data here instead of the new data you scraped? i think it should be `writer.writerow(row)`

Comment: @tripleee I have wrote the "read" step to be able to do the evaluation of the if condition, but somehow the problem I think relays in the fact that isn't able to find the data that it writes in the first loop in the csv. And somehow it "writes it temporarily" because when I run the program I'm able to see what it appended, but if I restart the computer, it's like nothing was appended.  I have found out that pandas for example returns a view "mode" and not a copy, I couldn't find out that this can be the case in here...

Comment: @diggusbickus at each loop all those variables get different values, and if the value couldn't be found in csv, should be written in the csv, otherwise should pass it... That's the idea... But somehow after it writes it in the csv at the second loop can't do the evaluation because it can't find the values, I think  and I have no idea why it's this the case

Comment: i don't think they get different values, you never do it in the code you gave. here: `if row[1] == hour and row[2] == race` you're testing the new values from row against old values (hour and race). when you get to the line writer.writerow, none of the variables has been updated to reflect the content of the new data so you keep writing the same line again and again

Comment: @diggusbickus it's mentioned at top, that after each loop the variables get different values. row[1] should correspond to the values of the column at index 1, which is "hour", so it should compare and evaluate if the value from the variable "hour" is in the column "hour", no? And the same for race...

Comment: The documentation you link to explains why you should not modify a _data frame_ you are currently looping over. You are not doing that, so the discussion about that is not relevant here.

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question to clarify the things we have been asking down here in the comments. Why and how is something here an endless loop? Do you have multiple threads or processes modifying the output file? Probably focus on either your logic error, and remove the parts about how to design this for endless processing, or vice versa.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, I'll try to clarify the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are checking each row and if it is not found you append your values. So if the CSV have 4 rows and none contains your data, you'll add the same data 4 times.
You should only check if the data exists with a boolean found = True . Then after you finish iterating the CSV if found is False you append your data.

Comment: your right, it appends the length of rows in csv the way it is now. I'll try to do this logic, don't know how for now . But there is one more thing that I forgot to mention, it seems that every time it appends, when I close the program and start it again, all my previous session couldn't be found... Probably because I didn't close the file at the end of the loop.